# SQL Server: This created score is multiplying by 4?

Tags: sql-server

The `TotalScore` result is 320 when it should just be 80(30 + 50) since the top 1 record for ProviderID 874 has `SessionsProgress` = 3 and the providerID is also present in the joined `SubscriptionsTV` table.

```
    DECLARE @ProviderID int = '874';

WITH cte as(
SELECT TOP 1 a.ProviderID, Time_Stamp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [AdditionalReports] = '1' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) as AdditionalReports,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [UniqueReportRequests] = '1' THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) as UniqueReportsRequests,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [SessionsProgress] > '0' THEN 30 ELSE 0 END) as SessionsProgress,
       MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END) as SubscriptionExists

       FROM ProviderValueCard a
       LEFT JOIN SubscriptionsTV b
         ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
       WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
       GROUP BY Time_Stamp, a.ProviderID, event
       ORDER BY event DESC, Time_Stamp DESC
    )
        SELECT ProviderID, Time_Stamp, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SessionsProgress + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
        FROM cte
```

Here are the 2 records for ProviderID 874 which only the most recent by `TimeStamp` is used.

```
ProviderID  AdditionalReports UniqueReportRequests Time_Stamp              AdditionalReportsNum UniqueReportsNum SessionsProgress AdditionalReportsNumQtr UniqueReportsNumQtr SurveyCompleted
----------- ----------------- -------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------------- ------------------- ---------------
874         0                 1                    2015-01-30 08:13:44.660 0                    55               3                0                       10                  1
874         0                 0                    2014-12-30 08:31:20.893 0                    0                3                0                       0                   1
```

Comment: There isn't a lot of information here. Can you create a sql fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sql fiddle and am not able to properly rebuild it there. Is there anything else I can add here specifically to give more info?

Comment: The problem is we can't see your screen or understand the problem. In order to get around that it is best if you can provide ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com is a great way to provide this information.